# 12.04 refuses to install with Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I have a desktop computer with windows 7 installed on it. Recently I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and burned the ISO image on a new blank DVD. After successfully burning DVD, I booted from the DAD. Ubuntu interface appeared asking me to either choose try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu. I chose to install Ubuntu. Again on next screen I choose to install Ubuntu inside Windows 7. After pressing continue button the following message appeared:

```
  checking battery state .............. ok
   checking for running unattended upgrades :
                                                acpid : exiting
speech dispatcher disabled ; edit /etc/default/ speech -dispatcher 

* Asking all remaining processes to terminate ............. ok 

Please remove installation media and close the tray (if any) then press enter :
```

Now the problem is that when I remove the installation media (i.e. the DVD) and press enter then instead of installing Ubuntu the computer reboots into Windows 7!

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and therefore do not know much about it. What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to download WUBI or dual boot ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7. In my case it was not the CD. I tried to install with several versions of Ubuntu and using USB or CD.

In my case the problem was fixed when I deleted the partition I made in windows prior to installation of Ubuntu. I don't know what was wrong but I just deleted it and allowed Ubuntu do it's own partition at the moment of installation. Maybe someone will find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your post, you choose "I choose to install ubuntu **inside windows 7**." I take that to mean that you were attempting a Wubi install.  Many others have opined that the Wubi method is not stable.

[Others have noticed that "install alongside Windows" option isn't available.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140186/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu12-04-along-side-windows7?lq=1)  I don't have evidence for your situation, but I suspect that option might not be available if Windows 7 is already using 4 primary partitions.

#### I recommend

1. Boot with the Ubuntu 12.04LTS or favorite installation CD, and choose "Try Ubuntu" from the menu.  From here, backup any Windows documents, videos...everything to an external drive or DVD-R (really anything).  Many people prefer to backup using a **disk image.**
2. Restart your computer with the disk in, and let Ubuntu **replace** Windows 7.  (UNLESS you require having access to a windows 7 machine sometimes)  The installer will handle the rest.

Many users will use a WINE compatibility program to run windows program on their Ubuntu machines so that they don't have to dual-boot, but WINE won't work for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the GRUB2 boot loader to the Master Boot Record usually solves this problem. It probably didn't get installed properly the first time. The rest of your Ubuntu system is most likely already set up correctly.

Ubuntu's community documentation explains various methods of [reinstalling GRUB2 to your MBR](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your installer. It might not have been burned to the CD properly.

The message you received is what I received when shutting down after the OS install. So if you receive that message immediately after you pressed "Continue" from choosing to install alongside Windows 7, you haven't really installed Ubuntu yet and hence you boot up to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS doesn't support more than 3 primary partitions. Use software like "EaseUs Partition manager" and check for the "Partition type".

If you have more than 3 primary make any one (other than windows installed drive) to logical by right clicking on the drive.

Reboot the system and install ubuntu. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever do that again, installing Ubuntu right from the boot menu. The best way to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration with Windows is to boot into the live session with your Ubuntu DVD or USB (choose **Try Ubuntu** instead of **Install Ubuntu** from the boot menu).

Once you are in the live session, all you have to do is to make sure you have an Internet connection running, and after that you can start the Live Ubuntu installer from the desktop. Choose the 3rd option provided by the installer which is **Something else** and when you get to the partition table you can use some raw partition at your choice, dividing it into 2 partitions, one large partition for root, and another small partition (up to 2GB in size) for Linux swap. You can format your root partition as Linux ext4 and choose foreslash **/** as startup or mount point.

Then you can select your root partition and press Next to begin installing Ubuntu. One last piece of advice, no matter how powerful your machine is, choose [Ubuntu 12.04.4](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) 32bit version instead of the 64bit version. It is the best choice if you want to go with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in dual boot with Windows.