# Upon installing Ubuntu 13.04, "acpid : exiting"

Tags: installation, 13.04, acpi

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.04 from DVD. I choose to install it alongside Window 7. The DVD was it self ejected and i got a black screen and `acpid : exiting` was written on upper right corner.

How can i fix it, to install Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "I choose to install it in Window 7". Did you choose to install it *alongside* or to *erase* Windows 7? Also I'm unsure far you got into the installation process. Please clarify and expand your question.

Comment: I choose to install it alongside window 7. After selecting it DVD was ejected and acpid : exiting was written on screen

Comment: No, i did not partitioned my hard drive

Comment: Seems similar to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150185/12-04-refuses-to-install-with-windows-7). Did you partition your hdd under Windows before attempting to install Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't see all those things written in that link, I only see acpid : exiting

Comment: Well, then I hope someone more knowledgeable can pick up the question. I've never seen this problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, when I was installing it on Compaq laptop. Original hard drive had 4 primary partitions. NTFS doesn't support more than 3? primary partitions. I didn't modify active and windows partition and converted 2 other to logical. After that everything start working just fine.

Comment: You need to add comments under Add Comment below the question. If you post them under Answer, followes get messed up.

Comment: My laptop has 500 GB hard drive, and I have two partitions both almost 250 GB. What are logical partitions? How can I make my partitions logical?