# Upon installing Ubuntu 13.10, “acpid : exiting”

Tags: installation

I'm unable to install Ubuntu 13.10. In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358811/upon-installing-ubuntu-13-04-acpid-exiting) they talk about partitioning. Please find the screenshot of my partitioning:

[image]

Please help me understand what I need to do?

UPDATE:

Please find below the gparted screenshot:

[image: gparted screenshot]

UPDATE:

When I follow Avinash Raj instructions I get stuck on step "Right click on the unallocated...". Below is the screenshot:

[image: in gparted I get stuck]

Comment: boot ubuntu live cd.select "try ubuntu" option.Connect to the internet and install gparted partition editor.And upload its screenshot.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have done what you said and put the screenshot into my original question.

Comment: if you want to install ubuntu,then you have to resize /dev/sda2 partition.How much space did you want for ubuntu partition?And how much do you want for swap partition?Give the details and i will post the answer for you.Did you have already installed windows on it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I was thinking 200GB for the Ubuntu partition, do you think it makes sense? I have 4GB Ram, can you please suggest a swap partition size. Yeah, I have Windows 7 installed.

Comment: @AvinashRaj You did not post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Boot ubuntu livecd,open up **gparted partition Editor**.
- Rightclick on the `/dev/sda2` partition and click on *Resize/Move* option.
- Then resize it to get 200 GB free unallocated space.The unallocated space was placed just below the `/dev/sda2` partition.
- Right click on the unallocated space and select *new* option.In the *create new partition* window select file system as ext4 and then click *add*(leave the other options as it is).
- Then run the ubuntu installer and select something else option.From the list of partitions,choose the created ext4 partition to install ubuntu.
- After that it asks for creating swap partition.Swap partition size must be double the RAM size in case of small sized RAM's probably(1 or 2 GB).

Comment: I get stuck on the step "Right click on the unallocated space...". Please find the screenshot in my original question. Not sure if I should destroy RECOVERY or HP_TOOLS. Is there another option?

Comment: To install Ubuntu I had to get rid of the RECOVERY and HP_TOOLS partitions and create a partition for Ubuntu and another one for swap. Thank you for your guidance.